# Add postgresql to grails 2.3.4

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-2.0

I have added the [postgresql plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/postgresql-extensions) from the grails page to my `Buildconfig.groovy`.

This is how the file looks like:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.tet.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'
        compile ":postgresql-extensions:0.6.1"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

However when I run `grails compile` I get the output:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.4
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: org/grails/plugins/postgresql-extensions/0.6.1/postgresql-extensions-0.6.1.pom
|Downloading: org/grails/plugins/postgresql-extensions/0.6.1/postgresql-extensions-0.6.1.zip
.
|Environment set to development
......
|Installing zip postgresql-extensions-0.6.1.zip...
...
|Installed plugin postgresql-extensions-0.6.1
....................
|Compiling 152 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:9: error: package org.postgresql.util does not exist
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;
                          ^
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class HstoreParser extends PGobject implements Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>> {
                                  ^
  symbol: class PGobject
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        this.type = "hstore";
            ^
  symbol: variable type
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        this.value = rawValue;
            ^
  symbol: variable value
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        this.type = "hstore";
            ^
  symbol: variable type
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        if (!"hstore".equals(this.type)) {
                                 ^
  symbol: variable type
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        this.value = rawValue;
            ^
  symbol: variable value
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
                    final char ch = value.charAt(++position);
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:220: error: cannot find symbol
                char ch = value.charAt(++position);
                          ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:225: error: cannot find symbol
                        final char nextCh = value.charAt(nextPosition);
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
                                sb = new StringBuilder(value.substring(firstQuotePosition + 1, nextPosition));
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
                String r = value.substring(firstQuotePosition + 1, position);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
                final char ch = value.charAt(position);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\grailsTestApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1\src\java\net\kaleidos\hibernate\usertype\HstoreParser.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
            final String r = value.substring(firstWordPosition, position + 1 );
                             ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class HstoreParser.HStoreIterator
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14 errors
1 error
```

What is wrong with my installation process?

I really appreciate your answer!

**Update**

I have added this to my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile (":postgresql-extensions:0.6.1") {
    excludes "hibernate"
}
```

However, I still get the same exceptions...

**Update 2**

This is how my BuildConfig.groovy looks now:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.tet.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        compile (":postgresql-extensions:0.6.1") {
            excludes "hibernate"
        }
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
        runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.4
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.postgresql:postgresql:zip:9.3-1100-jdbc41 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.postgresql:postgresql:zip:9.3-1100-jdbc41 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact org.postgresql:postgresql:zip:9.3-1100-jdbc41 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the postgresql-jdbc driver to your BuildConfig. Your `dependencies` section should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    runtime  'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
}
```

Then it should compile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I still get an error when I am using `grails compile`. Please see my update 2!

Comment: You have to put the driver into the dependencies section, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thx a lot it works! Btw one further question is the onliest way on grails to test if the postgresql db is correctly configured via implementing a CRUD method or is there a quicker way?

Comment: @user1000 If you configure your data source in grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy, Grails will complain if the data base configuration is invalid or the database connection can't be established. Beyond this, you probably have to resort to using bootstrap code or the database migration plugin.